# key up event not firing on letter/number keys

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

When i release a letter or number key i don't get key up events. When i release enter/alt/arrows/space i see the output. key down fires for all keys. Any ideas on what is it?

Edit: for clarity - Keys is the main class.

Edit 2: I am using flexSDK 4.6

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class Keys extends Sprite {
    public function Keys() {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onkeyUp);
    }
    private function onKeyDown(e:KeyboardEvent){
        trace("1 "+e.keyCode);
    }
    private function onkeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent){
        trace("0 "+e.keyCode);
    }
}
}
```

Things get interesting if i add a text field with type of "input" to stage. If i focus the text field keyUp events start working if i however press keys when stage has focus keyUp events do not fire.

Comment: I'd recommend not adding the listeners until the Keys instance has been added to the stage, but if you're getting some then that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I removed the Flex tag; as this has nothing to do w/ Flex . If memory serves me; something that accepts input must have focus for the Key events to dispatch.  I think I solved that issue in my Flex/AIR Game by using the FocusManager to give Focus to the game board.

Comment: @wvxvw Flex is an SDK; which includes a compiler and a UI Framework.  However, the code in this post has no dependencies to the Framework.  There is no indication in the post how the code is compiled. If using an ActionScript only project in Flash Builder 4.7; then the new "non-Flex" compiler is used.

Comment: @wvxvw With Flash Builder 4.7; Adobe has introduced a new compiler, which is used for non-Flex projects.  This was built under the code named "Falcon".  It is not part of Flex.  An early build was donated to the Apache Flex project. It is not expected that Adobe will donate future changes to Apache; so I expect the 'Adobe' Falcon compiler and the 'Apache' Falcon compiler will divert significantly; especially when ActionScript 4 and the new Flash VM is released.

Comment: @wvxvw He does say he is using Flex.  In this case; I am probably making too many assumptions.  Many posts mix up Flex and Flash Builder.

Comment: I am not using flash builder i am using IntelliJ IDEA 11.1 with flex SDK 4.6 and i have a debug player... nothing is broken except for the fact that no events are fired on specific keys while other keys trigger the events just fine